# How to write specific number of characters in txt file in java

Tags: java

I want to write a file with random character in java.

like the file can contain numbers, letters and special characters.

For Ex. Maximum characters it can have is 2000, and I want the number 6 to be written 419 times.

What I've done so far is creating and writing on the file

```
public void createFile(){

    try{
        fileCreator = new Formatter("test.txt");
        //fileCreator = new Formatter(System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\testFolder\\test.txt");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    System.out.println(fileCreator);
}

private void addToFile(){

    String uniqueUserID = jTextField1.getText();
    String uniqueCodeID = jTextField2.getText();

    fileCreator.format("%s%s%s", uniqueUserID," " ,uniqueCodeID);
    fileCreator.close();
}
```

Is this way to write good or should I do it other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define two ranges for numbervalue and how often you want to print this.

```
int minNumber=0, maxNumber=9;
int minPrint=1, maxPrint=2000;
Random random = new Random();
int number = random.nextInt((maxNumber - minNumber) + 1);   // random between 0-9
int printTimes = random.nextInt((maxPrint - minPrint) + 1); // 1 - 2000
```

When you got this you just need to loop for `printTimes` and print/add the generated number.

And ofcause you can generate a new number to print before each printing.

---

Gernerate a random letter:

- Take a String of all values and pick a random index of it.

  ```
  String values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //add a-z, 0-9, etc
  char letter = values.charAt(random.nextInt(values.length()));
  ```
- Take the ASCII Table and pick generate a random number between A-Z and parse it to char. (A=65 min, Z=90 max) Have look upside for the code.

Comment: I am aware of it, but how to write that much in?

Comment: open/create the File. Clear it before you loop the writing into it, because limit of 2000. append the file with the number in the loop over your `printTimes`. --> I will post code when you´ve tried something. You just asked for generating a number and i´ve done this. Now try next yourself step by step.

Comment: oh, got your point! thanks for that. 

but how could I do it for letters too? from A to Z?  and characters too?

Comment: Have a look now. I would take the first way because its better readable which values can be picked.